# How to activate a textarea with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have a textarea (#textarea), which I want to "activate" when a button (#activate) is clicked. By "activate", I mean the blinking prompt should appear and you should be able to type into the textarea. In other words, clicking on `#activate` should have the same effect as clicking on the actual textarea.

```
<div id="activate">ACTIVATE</div>

<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :text, id:"textarea" %>
  <%= f.submit "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

Is this possible using jQuery?

Comment: Did you try doing `$('#textareaid').focus();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

```js
$('#activate').click(function() {
  $('#textarea').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="activate">ACTIVATE</div>

<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant event is called focus. With jQuery you can set focus like this:

```
$('#textarea').focus();
```